# Is there any reduction formula possible?

Tags: definite-integrals

$$ I=\int_{0}^ {\pi} e^{x} (sinx)^{n} dx $$.
I tried a lot but unable to obtain and stuck by it.

Comment: Maybe you wouldn’t mind sharing what you tried, so that people don’t keep repeating your errors?

Answer (score 4):

**hint**

integrate by parts twice to find a recursive formula between $I_n $ and $I_{n-2} $.

$$I_n=-n\int_0^\pi \sin^{n-1}(x)\cos (x)e^xdx $$
$$=n \int_0^\pi \Bigl((n-1)(\sin^{n-2}(x)-\sin^n (x))-\sin^n (x)\Bigr)e^xdx $$

Comment: Should i first integrate it twice, by parys method .

Comment: @GirishKumarChandora Yes. $u=sin^n v'=e^x$

Comment: thnks a lot for giving hint. Now i did it.

Comment: @GirishKumarChandora If that helped, there’s a check mark you can hit to indicate that as the correct answer for your purposes.